# Extract files from Chrome OS / Chromebook recovery image

Tags: netflix, google-chrome-os, chromebook, widevine

**My Problem**: I am trying get hold of the official Chrome WideVine CDM plugin for an ARM architecture.

**My Understanding So Far**: Given ARM-based Chromebooks can stream Netflix (and Netflix uses the WideVine CRM plugin), I am lead to believe a Chrome OS installation should contain the files I'm after. As I don't have access to an ARM-based Chromebook, my next best is a Chromebook recovery image.

**Where I'm up to**: I have downloaded a *HP Chromebook 11* recovery image, `chromeos_6812.88.0_daisy-skate_recovery_stable-channel_skate-mp.bin`, [from here](https://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chromeos/recovery/chromeos_6812.88.0_daisy-skate_recovery_stable-channel_skate-mp.bin.zip) (the HP Chromebook 11 is ARM-based)

**What I'd like to do next**: Extract two files from the recovery image.

*Note*: I don't have access to an ARM based Chromebook to just copy the files from :/

Does anyone know how I could do such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.bin` file is just a disk image that contains many partitions. You can "load" the image by running `sudo kpartx -av chromeos_6812.88.0_daisy-skate_recovery_stable-channel_skate-mp.bin` (the `-v` is for verbose mode). This will load 12 partitions (from `/dev/mapper/loop0p1` to `/dev/mapper/loop0p12`) and make them available for mounting, and you should see some additional drives in your file manager.

In this case, the partition you're looking for is labelled `ROOT-A`, and corresponds to the third partition (`/dev/mapper/loop0p3`). For some reason, opening it in my file manager directly didn't work, so I had to mount it manually by running `sudo mount -t ext2 /dev/mapper/loop0p3 -o ro /media/saikrishna/chromeos/`. This will mount the `ext2` partition in read-only mode in the `/media/saikrishna/chromeos` directory (change the last part to an existing empty directory on your system).

To remove the mappings, run `sudo kpartx -dv chromeos_6812.88.0_daisy-skate_recovery_stable-channel_skate-mp.bin`. If that doesn't print out anything (which was the case for me), run `sudo kpartx -dv /dev/loop0`.

Comment: After a quick `sudo apt-get install kpartx`, I was able to run that command. The partitions showed up as `/dev/mapper/sdc1` -> `/dev/mapper/sdc12` for me, but the numbers where the same, so I mounted `/dev/mapper/sdc3`, and was good to go. Thanks!